# Create-React-App: Runtime error - super() hasn't been called

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

Updated create-react-app from 1.1.5 to 2.0.3
Upgrade working fine and running locally with no errors.
Building with no errors.
For some reason I get the following error at runtime with my build:

> ReferenceError: this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called

The only thing that has changed in my package.json is my react script to 2.0.3. So guessing this could be possibly related updates to babel or webpack. 
Anyone encountered an error similar to this?

Comment: you are declaring constructor(){} in a class but super is not defined. 
`class App extends Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
 }
 ...
}`

Comment: @AvinashMahlawat declared constructor and super is defined. Looks like some sort of an issue with the compiled build at runtime. If I reset react-scripts to 1.1.5 works ok again. Thinking it could be something to do with babel or webpack updates possibly. 
As the code is running ok in development mode it (the build) is failing only at runtime.

Comment: Just wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue or something similar?